# Taking the derivative of a matrix multiplied by a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that, if $A$ is a real $m\times n$ matrix, with $f: R^n\to R^m$ as $f(x) = Ax$ then $f'(x) = A$ for all $x$ in  $R^n$

I am not sure how to take the derivative of $f$ though. I know that if I multiply $Ax$ I will get a vector in $R^m$, and I can take the derivative of that, but then I won't be anywhere close to $f'(x) = A$

EDIT:

The definition of a derivative I am using is that the first derivative is a $m \times n$ matrix of first-order partial derivatives.

Comment: What definition of derivative are you using?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese I just edited the question to show.

Comment: In your definition, do you mean an $m\times n$ matrix?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Oh, yes. Whoops. I just fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

The derivative you refer to is sometimes called the Frechet derivative. Given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^m$, its Frechet derivative at $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $f^\prime(x)$, is the unique $m\times n$ matrix that satisfies

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{||f(y)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)(y-x)||}{||y-x||}=0.$$

Here $||\cdot||$ denotes the standard norm of a vector in Euclidean space. In your case, $f(x)=Ax$ and you can verify directly from this definition that $f^\prime(x)=A$ as follows:

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{||f(y)-f(x)-A(y-x)||}{||y-x||}=\lim_{y\rightarrow x}\frac{0}{||y-x||}=0.$$

Of course, it takes a little bit of work to prove that $f^\prime(x)$, when it exists, is unique, but this can be done very generally. It is a good exercise to prove this fact yourself.